# Eclipse fails to build android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

Background: this problem occured after an update through the android sdk Manager eclipse plugin.

Currently, when i try to build any android project, this error occurs.
[image]

THe information i gathered so far, is that this is a java related issue, as i'm trying to compile newer version code (version 52.0 stands for java 8) and run it in an older one. However, most of the solutions didn't work out.

Here are the compile setting for an android project :

[image]

Here are settings from the java compiler in Eclispe:

[image]

Here are the installed JREs
[image]

Finally, installed packets from the Android SDK:

[image]

I've  removed the packets for API 23, but with no luck. Could it be that Android tools are causing trouble, since the SKD doesn't support the java version (52)?

Comment: it doesnt prove support for android anymore

Comment: Re-installing the JDK/JRE did it, Still wonder what was triggered by the android update that cause this.

Comment: if you will see google has announced that support for eclipse will be out for api level > 22. better you switch to AS as early as possible

Comment: I'm aware. Still, this is not the question at hand, since it's working now. Refrain from repeating yourself, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with JDK/JRE. They were installed separately. Deleted them and installed from a bundle. Although they were the same version, project building kept on crashing.